# How to avoid duplicate declarations of Q_DECLARE_METATYPE<aCommonType>

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

My project consists of an app that links to two static libraries. Each of the libraries declares `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE< QUuid >`, in order to use `QUuid` with `QVariant`, which leads to a `'redefinition of struct QMetaTypeId< QUuid >'` error.

What is the correct way to go about this while keeping the ability to use each library on its own in different projects?

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't get "redefinition of struct 'QUuid'". Only the author of "QUuid" should declare that metatype id. Otherwise it's only a question of time until you run into this problem.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb QUuid is declared in Qt headers. I don't have control over that code, but I still want to use that type in QVariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you can call the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro from the implementation files that need it instead of calling it from the header files, or [as the documentation suggests](http://qt-project.org/doc/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE), call it from private headers in each library.

But because `QUuid` stores its content as a `QByteArray` which is already supported by `QVariant`, you don't need to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` to do that (from Qt 4.8 only):

```
// QVariant variant;
// QUuid uuid;
variant = uuid.toByteArray();
uuid = variant.toByteArray();
```

or the same thing, but a little less efficiently, with `QString` (before Qt 4.8):

```
variant = uuid.toString();
uuid = variant.toString();
```

And since `QVariant` will implicitly convert between `QString` and `QByteArray`, you can mix  `toString` and `toByteArray` without any problem.

Comment: What is the exact criteria for implementation files that need `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`? I added it to all files that set/get QUuid in/from a QVariant, as well as all files that inspect QVariant type name and act on it. Things seem to work, no compile errors, and all data seems to be read/written correctly. Can I rely on the lack of compile errors to be sure Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is correctly declared whenever it's needed? In theory, could there be silent failures in getting/setting QVariant values because of these modifications?

Comment: Note that I can't use the `QString` or `QByteArray` approach, since in a lot of parts of my code I don't know in advance that I'm expecting a `QUuid`. I need `QVariant` to be able to identify the stored value as `QUuid`.

Comment: @szayat As long as you only use `QUuid` with `QVariant`, if it compiles, you won't have any warning later at runtime. You would only get warnings if you were using `QUuid` as a parameter in a queued signal/slot connection or `invokeMethod` before calling `qRegisterMetaType`, or if you wanted to serialize the `QVariant` containing the `QUuid` on a `QDataStream` without calling `qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators`.